# R forcats - Is it possible to rename "other" in fct_lump?

Tags: r, forcats

Using fct_lump to group variables I need to have the grouped data "Other" renamed, is it possible?

If so, how can it be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: `forcats::fct_lump` has an argument `other_level` to achieve that, e.g.`forcats::fct_lump(..., other_level = "My Other Level")`. See `?forcats::fct_lump`.

Comment: yes!  thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
fct_other(f, keep, drop, other_level = "Other")
```

or in your case other_level = "MyLabel"